# Can I use MacOS tccutil to reset ScreenRecording permissions for a daemon that has no bundleID?

Tags: macos, privacy, screen-capture, launch-agent

I have a LaunchdAgent (e.g. /etc/someDir/myAgent) running, which asks permission to record the screen. System Popup pops - user permits screen-recording in the System-Preferences "Security & Privacy" panel, the "Privacy" tab. It is clearly visible there.

Now when I wish to uninstall/remove this agent, I also want to remove its permissions.

I should be able to use the tccutil command-line tool to either

```
tccutil reset ALL myAgent
```

or

```
tccutil reset ScreenCapture myAgent
```

However, I always receive the following error:

> tccutil: No such bundle identifier "myAgent": The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)

I tried to use the path to the launchAgent, its label "com.mycompany.myAgent" from the .plist I install in /Library/LaunchAgents to run it, I even tried unique identifiers from its [NSProcessInfo processInfo] -- to no avail.

man tccutil is worthless, and I cannot find any documentation on the subject.

Idea anyone? how can I clear privacy database of my Agent once it is no longer needed?

Comment: You can either reset it for all apps (`tccutil reset ScreenCapture`) and re-enable other apps if required. Or you can try to get bundle identifier via `osascript -e 'id of app "MyApp"'`. Also label from the plist is not a bundle identifier. What's inside `ProgramArguments` (plist)?

Comment: I know - but I do not want to disturb other applications and services. Especially that I'm doing this on a customer's Mac --- I just want to remove the permission from MY component at the time I un-install it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the app's *bundle identifier* to the `tccutil reset` command. That's the value for the `CFBundleIdentifier` property in the app's Info.plist, not the display name or executable name.

For single-binary (rather than bundled) executables, you can embed the Info.plist directly into the binary, which opens up a bunch of features which require a bundle identifier, such as entitlements, etc.. If using Xcode to build, enable the "Create Info.plist Section in Binary" target setting. Otherwise, you'll have to manually add the `--sectcreate __info_plist` option during linking.)

Another option is to place the executable inside a generic `.bundle` target. Then the bundle identifier of the bundle applies.

Comment: As I said - my component is a single-file  unix-style binary, that has no "bundle ID". That's the source of my problem. Not everything in this world is an "app". TCC seems to support applying entitlements to such executables - but tccutil won't address them.

Comment: You probably should try an [embedded Info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4022495/48660) in that case. If using Xcode to build, enable the "Create Info.plist Section in Binary" target setting. Otherwise, you'll have to manually add the `--sectcreate __info_plist` option during linking.) This lets you assign a bundle identifier, which in turn allows you to do things that require one.

Comment: Just to complete this mini-discussion. We embedded info.plist in our single-file binary component, to no avail. TCC does NOT consult this info.plist, and does not identify our binary by bundle-ID, but rather by its full-path. tccutil won't let me remove/reset by this bundle-id. So... nice try.

Comment: That leaves the final option, putting the executable inside a bundle, whether or not it otherwise needs to be. [The official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/signing-a-daemon-with-a-restricted-entitlement?language=objc) says you should put it in an `.app` bundle, but I've deployed a launch agent that required screen capture consent inside a plain `.bundle` bundle with a suitable Info.plist. (This is the macOS -> Framework & Library -> Bundle template in Xcode) The .app bundle option may have the advantage of letting you set an icon.

Comment: I really wish I could... That's a corporate management decision to deploy as "unix binaries" and not proper MacOS deployment. There are many other aspects for which I would wrap a product in a proper bundle (BTW you don't need a raw .bundle -- there are many standard code-bundled you could use (A Preferences Panel, a Plugin, a Menu-bar status-item App, A System-Extension, Network-filter extension, Audio-component and so on. Also - I'm quite sure with the correct entries in your info.plist - also a .bundle can have a proper icon.